# Standard ML comment formatting is faulty in vim

Tags: vim, comments, sml

I have tried the following commands for formatting comments in `~/.vim/after/indent/sml.vim`

```
set comments=s1:(*,mb:*,ex:*)
set comments=sr:(*,mb:*,ex:*)
set comments=s1:(*,mb:\ *,ex:*)
set comments=sr:(*,mb:*,ex:*)
```

and so on with various combinations. I simply cannot seem to achieve C-style commenting where the middle comment line is indent by 1 space. Instead of this

```
(* Text
 * More text
 * even more text *)
```

I get this

```
(*
* Some misaligned text
* etc. *)
```

Any suggestions? `:h format-options comments fo-table` don't suggest any alternatives that seem useful.

Answer (score 0):

When I use those settings,

```
set comments=s1:(*,mb:*,ex:*)
set comments=sr:(*,mb:*,ex:*)
set comments=s1:(*,mb:\ *,ex:*)
set comments=sr:(*,mb:*,ex:*)
```

I get the following results,

```
(* blah blah blah blah blah adsf blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 * blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 * blah blah blah blah blah blah ...
```

This works regardless of whether I

- `set formatoptions+=t` and `set textwidth=80` and exceeding the line,
- `set formatoptions+=r` and hit Enter,
- `set formatoptions+=o` and hit `o`/`O` in command mode, or
- `set formatoptions+=q` and hit `gq`

with `au Filetype sml source ~/.vim/after/indent/sml.vim` in my ~/.vimrc.

This is the default Vim on Ubuntu 15.04:

```
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:32)
Included patches: 1-52
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
...
```

Maybe you have some other setting or plugin that affects this behaviour.

Comment: I tried disabling all my plugins and use a bare mininum config:
    `set nocompatible
    filetype plugin indent on
    syntax enable`
and got the same result.This is (g)Vim on Windows, version 7.4.